# Exception in template helper: TypeError: _.mapObject is not a function

Tags: meteor, underscore.js

I have facing the below issue while using `underscorejs` running on meteor.

> "Exception in template helper: TypeError: _.mapObject is not a
>   function"

Please advise.

```
  var types = _.groupBy(areaFlatten, 'category');
        console.log(types);
        var result = **_.mapObject**(types, function(val, key) {
        return  _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) {
          return memo + v.val;
        }, 0) / val.length * 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using an older version of Underscore. `_.mapObject` was added in v1.8.0 (http://underscorejs.org/#changelog)

Alternative without using `_.mapObject`:

```
var types = _.groupBy(areaFlatten, 'category');
console.log(types);
var result = {};
_.each(types, function(val, key) {
    result[key] = _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) {
      return memo + v.val;
    }, 0) / val.length * 10;
});
```

If you are going to use this functionality regularly, you could add a mixin to make the function available until you get a chance to upgrade, see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lradh7jd/1/

```
_.mixin({
  mapObject: function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    var output = {};
    _.each(obj, function(v, k) {
        output[k] = iteratee.apply(context || this, arguments);
    });
    return output;
  }
});
```

Comment: how to upgrade underscorejs in meteorjs

Comment: Any alternative instead of _.mapObject